# rangecolumn chart yValues (high, low)

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I have a recordset that includes Name, Start Date and End Date.  My most recent try in C#

```
var qryInQA = db.Query(qry);

var myChart = new Chart(width: 800, height: 400) 
   .AddTitle("Days in QA") 
   .AddSeries(chartType: "RangeColumn",
      xValue: qryInQA, xField: "Name",
      LowValue: "dtStart",
      HighValue: "dtEnd") 
   .AddLegend()
   .Write();
```

I have also tried:

```
yValues: qryInQA, yFields: "dtStart",
yValues: qryInQA, yFields: "dtEnd",
```

And:

```
yValues: qryInQA, yFields: "dtStart, dtEnd",
```

EACH WITH various error messages.  Adding a 2nd series (`.AddSeries`) only creates a 2nd column next to the first.

I would assuming the same logic would apply to a candlestick or stock chart (with four y-values).

Comment: And the errors are....?

Comment: (1) CS1739: The best overload for 'AddSeries' does not have a parameter named 'LowValue'

(2) CS1740: Named argument 'yValues' cannot be specified multiple times

(3) System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Data points insertion error. Only 1 Y values can be set for this data series. 
Parameter name: yFields

Comment: Poor documentation from Microsoft actually. I am having the same issue. Couldn't find the code sample how we can set those high and low yvalues.